# internal speaker not working ubuntu 10.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a dv6000 laptop . My speaker and mic were working few days ago . But now only external speaker works. 
Can anyone suggest me some solutions please.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the microphone or the speaker not working? Did you update your distro recentrly, and which version are you running?

Comment: I haven't updated my distro recently. I always get the updates available and the last time I guess linux kernel was updated . I am using ubuntu 10.10 .

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
lsmod|grep pcspkr
```

Make sure that 'pcspkr' is loaded and if not do:

```
modprobe pcspkr
```

If it is loaded try running alsamixer from the console and use the arrow keys to control the levels of your various inputs/outputs one of them should be labeled "System" or "PC Speaker"

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.But didn't work on my laptop. I didn't see System or PC Speaker in my alsamixer.